# phaser3 tutorial html pages not loading

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Trying Phaser 3 for the first time. The every html pages in the "Making your first Phaser 3 game" tutorial just doesn't load. In particular, the tutorial shows part3.html page with blue 'sky' image loaded. But when i open it, it loads nothing, just blank page.

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Making your first Phaser 3 Game - Part 3</title>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.15.1/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update
        }
    };

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload ()
    {
        this.load.image('sky', 'C:\wamp64\www\assets\sky.png');
        this.load.image('ground', 'C:\wamp64\www\assets\platform.png');
        this.load.image('star', 'C:\wamp64\www\assets\star.png');
        this.load.image('bomb', 'C:\wamp64\www\assets\bomb.png');
        this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'C:\wamp64\www\assets\dude.png', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
    }

    function create ()
    {
        this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
    }

    function update ()
    {
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've only altered assets location in preload function. Tried both windows and linux file path absolute and relative. Still nothing.

Oddly enough, the index.html page from 'getting started with phaser' works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.15.1/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        physics: {
            default: 'arcade',
            arcade: {
                gravity: { y: 200 }
            }
        },
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create
        }
    };

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload ()
    {
        this.load.setBaseURL('http://labs.phaser.io');

        this.load.image('sky', 'assets/skies/space3.png');
        this.load.image('logo', 'assets/sprites/phaser3-logo.png');
        this.load.image('red', 'assets/particles/red.png');
    }

    function create ()
    {
        this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');

        var particles = this.add.particles('red');

        var emitter = particles.createEmitter({
            speed: 100,
            scale: { start: 1, end: 0 },
            blendMode: 'ADD'
        });

        var logo = this.physics.add.image(400, 100, 'logo');

        logo.setVelocity(100, 200);
        logo.setBounce(1, 1);
        logo.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

        emitter.startFollow(logo);
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I kinda suspected this has to do something with html header part so I copied index's header part and pasted on part3. Then the part3 doesn't show any blank page this time but instead it shows black screen with green box in the middle.

What should I fix in the original part3.html code?
and What is the correct file path for phaser?

Comment: You have to escape your backslashes, so `C:\wamp64\www\assets\sky.png` should actually be `C:\\wamp64\\www\\assets\\sky.png`

Comment: Also, if you take a look at the browser's console, it's probably telling you where stuff went wrong.

Comment: I figured it out. It turns out the src script was no longer valid. I changed it to valid one and changed assets path as well(Since chrome wants http filepath). But now the chrome browser is refusing to load  the png file and saids "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present"

Comment: Are you running it from the http server or are you just opening the html file in chrome?

Comment: I'm using wampserver. asset folder and html files are at web root (i.e. http://localhost/assets/sky.png). Seriously, i don't think this is suppose to be this complicated. I don't know where did i strayed.

Comment: No wait I didn't load the html through my local server. GODDAMNIT Now it finally works. Thanks bro!

Comment: No problem :) Good luck with your learning